# The function 'notifyListeners' isn't defined. Try importing the library that defines 'notifyListeners',

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

For some reason I am getting this error although i have already imported the library . I tried flutter clean but nothing works.

```
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

class Product with ChangeNotifier {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final double price;
  final String imageUrl;
  bool isFavourite; //This is not final as it will change again again

  Product(
      {required this.description,
      required this.id,
      required this.imageUrl,
      this.isFavourite = false,
      required this.price,
      required this.title});
}

void toggleFavouriteStatus(bool isFavourite) {
  isFavourite = !isFavourite;
  notifyListeners();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're putting the method *outside* the class, when it should be inside:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

class Product with ChangeNotifier {
  // ...

  void toggleFavouriteStatus(bool isFavourite) {
    isFavourite = !isFavourite; 
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Also, you probably don't need a parameter in this method, since it just toggles the value:

```
  void toggleFavouriteStatus() {
    isFavourite = !isFavourite; 
    notifyListeners();
  }
```